# How to display a QPixmap in QWebEngine?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qimage, qpixmap

I'm trying to figure out what is the best and most efficient way to display a QPixmap or a QImage in a QWebEngine frame.

My goal is to display a video that is being loaded from a custom network camera, which we have a C++ API, in the QWebEngine frame, with maximum efficiency. So saving the frames to the disk and then loading them on the QWebEngine frame, is not an option.

Previously, I was using Qt WebKit and it was pretty straight forward to load a QPixmap created in C++, because it was accessible through a Javascript object. But now, I'm interested in QWebEngine due to multiple purposes.

However, in QWebEngine, it seems that there is no way to directly attach QObjects to the frame window object.

So my question is what is the most efficient way to transfer a image, or a byte array, to be shown in QWebEngine?

Comment: IMHO there is no need for QWebEngine in this task at all. With widgets that is simply pushing of QPixmap to some label with update() call. See QLabel::setPixmap() call. With QML it is also no big deal. And I know that for sure. A timer on UI thread will do that push with applicable frame rate. I actually do that precisely with some network camera.

Answer (score 2):

One of the fastest ways to draw QPixmap is QGraphicsScene::addPixmap. And it is very comfortable way. Or just draw it on QLabel.

Drawing pixmap with QWebEngine and JS is really bad idea. It is slow and WebEngine is big Chromium browser under the hood, so it is + about ~60 mb libraries.

> My goal is to display a video that is being loaded from a custom
>   network camera, which we have a C++ API

If you need only this as you said, you don't need QWebEngine, only your network method to obtain image and QGraphicsScene to draw. It is really fast and good for video.

But if you want it so much you can, for example, paste image with JS through clipboard :)